# Login Database C# without SQL

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So I'm making a personal project in Visual Studio C#

I'm very new to C# and coding in general. I created a login panel and I want a way to store data without the need of a database server, more like a text file.

It would store as shown

```
--------------------
      Profiles
[Username] [Password]
Admin       123abc
Test        imboss
--------------------
```

and after all that it have a checking method to see if
usernameTextBox and passwordTextBox are equal to any of the profiles.

```
private void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username, password;
    username = textBox1.Text;
    password = textBox2.Text;


    if ("userProfileName".ToString() == username && "userPassword".ToString() == password)
    {
        //login
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have entered a wrong user name or password!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to know how to make a little table to store values( username & password ) and a way to check if the username and password imputed is equal to any of the passwords in the table. Without the use of SQL

Comment: You'd be better off using some kind of strucutred text like JSON and serialize/deserialize using objects.

Comment: Would there be a way to just store the info into the c# code like example             table { [0]="User","password", [1]="admin","123abc"}

Comment: You should never store passwords, but store a hash of them instead.  They should also have a unique salt - which means it doesn't matter if it's the same as another user's password.  Also - you don't need to `ToString()` something that's already a string.  Take a look at `SqlLite` or `RavenDb` or search for no-sql for a good way of storing data without SQL Server.

Comment: Investigate [`StreamWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`StreamReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: You can easily store data in a text file in any number of formats.  JSON, XML, CSV, fixed-width, serialized C# data structure, etc.  Are you asking for advice on which one to use or on how to implement one of those specifically?  SQL Server or another database system is the ideal choice for a real application, and none of them are suitable for storing a clear-text password to test, as others have pointed out.

Comment: I want to know how to implement any really, I'm just trying to store lets say 10 username and passwords for me and friends to use.

Comment: @Biologic - You can use a System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach would be to store the username and password in the app.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Admin" value="123abc"/>
    <add key="Test" value="imboss"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

The values can be read from the file with the ConfigurationManger class. To use the class you will need to add a reference and using statement to the top of your file.

```
        var userPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[username];

        if (userPassword == password)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome");
        } else {
            MessageBox.Show("You have entered a wrong user name or password!");
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Biologic you thank people by clicking the green checkmark at the upper-left of the answer.